# Sometime website frontend changes not reflecting in browser and loading with older version of website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, opencart2.x

I can somebody tell me how to load website (Opencart website) with latest changes. Sometime not (always) when I made some front end changes like in html or css, these changes are not going to reflect in browser. But work once cleared browser history and cache.

So how can I do this task in my code. so user no need to refresh or clear cache in browser

Comment: press ctrl+F5. Then it will load latest changes.

Comment: @pravin you must disable cache from server side.

Comment: hello, Faiyaz can you tell me how to disable cache from server. I mean is it possible in coding or its cpanel changes?

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+F5. Then it will load latest changes.

Comment: But can't tell that to every user. So I want that solution which I can implements at my end and user can see my updated page not old one

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers simply allow you to press ctrl and click the reload button but, if you want to go with full keyboard, ctrl + F5.  This is a reload that skips the cache.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes for this issue. The first one is your browser cache. Sometimes your browser (specially Google Chrome) will show you a cached copy of your website instead of showing the new one. To resolve this issue, you need to simply hit `CTRL + F5` (or `Cmd + R` in Mac) buttons on your keyboard to reload the page.

**or**

You can't force a user to do do this. But you can try to prevent the user's browser from caching the page in the first place. For example, you can use meta elements like so:

`<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="TUE, 21 June 2016 05:00:00 GMT">`

`<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">`

But that's not totally reliable (the user's ISP might cache the page anyway), and perhaps out of date. Another, perhaps more robust option, is to use HTTP headers, as explained here:

**Learn more about it**

http://securityevaluators.com/knowledge/case_studies/caching/

https://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/

Comment: Thank you. but it will work for my browser? what about other user?

Comment: for your application and use  this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />`

Comment: Thanks..But if I use this solution then will website take a time to load as it will load every time from server and not cache?